# React CORS with URL Param despite setting CORS policy on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch

So I am trying to make a fetch request to get data before component loads using componentWillMount, but it keeps throwing error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/mine/1/user_list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Now I did try all solution proposed in other related question. Some of the things that I tried was setting 'Allow-CORS' param in the header. Also I have Google chrome tool that turns the CORS on and it is already on. Apart from that I also have tried keeping parameter in the fetch request with the mode.

But it is not working. Interesting thing is that if I try with constant URL (for example, http://locahost:5000/maintenance/company/fetch) the request goes through fine without any issue. However, when I use custom path URL as shown below (http://localhost:5000 + "mine/" + activeSite + "/user_list";) then issue starts. I have attached small snippet of the code for your reference.

My backend is in Python3 flask-restplus. It doesn't receive the request on backend. Error is thrown before even it makes fetch request. My controller has no such policy on for CORS on backend. But I assume if other request works fine in the app this should work fine without having that policy in the backend. Also I tested function with Swagger-UI and it works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { serverConst } from "../constants/system";
import { getAuthHeader } from "../helper/authHeader";

class TaskForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      assigned: "",
      assigner: [],
      reporter_list: [],
      operationSucceed: false,
      error: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let activeSite = localStorage.getItem("activeMinesite");
    if (activeSite) {
      const request_url = serverConst.SERVER_URL + "mine/" + activeSite + "/user_list";
      fetch(request_url, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: getAuthHeader()
      }).then(response => {
        response.json().then(json => {
          console.log(response);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```